# Issue showing a selected id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am having an issue getting tabs to open based on the selection I am choosing. In the snippet you will see 4 boxes. If you click on box 1, I am wanting `#marketing1` to open below it and so on.

The method I am using is to get the specific id of the button selection (the 1,2,3,4 box) and then declare a variable to just get the number. Then to add that number to the id of `#marketing` to show the appropriate section. I am not sure what I am doing wrong. No errors are showing.

Ps - I am also trying to add an `.active` class to the `#marketing-service` for when one of the selection boxes is clicked on to show my the active class (it creates a down arrow under the box. Am I implementing the `.active` wrong to the `:before` and `:after`?

```js
//For tabs to stay active
 $('.marketing-service').click(function() {
  $('.marketing-service.active').removeClass('active');
  $(this).toggleClass('active');
  
  //To get the service display box to show
  var item_number = $(this).attr('id').replace('marketing-tab', '');
  /* $('html, body').animate({
  scrollTop: $("#service-display-box").offset().top
   }, 1500);*/
  $('#marketing'+item_number).show().siblings('.marketing-section-wrap').hide();
 });
```

```css
.marketing-section-wrap, .marketing-section-wrap-main {
 width: 100%;
 height: auto;
 padding: 80px 0;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #EBEBEB;
}
.marketing-section-wrap {
 display: none;
}
#marketing-services {
 width: 95%;
 margin: 0 2.5%;
}
.marketing-service {
 display: inline-block;
 width: 22%;
 margin: 0 1%;
 height: 400px;
 background: #F0F0F0;
 position: relative;
 cursor: pointer;
}
.marketing-service:first-child {
 margin-left: 0;
}
.marketing-service:last-child {
 margin-right: 0;
}
.marketing-service:hover {
 background: rgba(0, 255, 170, .4);
 z-index: 1;
}
/*-- Down Arrow for boxes --*/
.marketing-service:after.active, .marketing-service:before.active {
 top: 100%;
 left: 50%;
 border: solid transparent;
 content: " ";
 height: 0;
 width: 0;
 position: absolute;
}
.marketing-service:after.active {
 border-width: 0px;
 margin-left: 0px;
 border-color: rgba(136, 183, 213, 0);
 border-right-color: #88b7d5;
 margin-top: -30px;
}
.marketing-service:before.active {
 border-color: #FFF;
 border-top-color: #88b7d5;
 border-width: 36px;
 margin-left: -36px;
 margin-top: 0;
}
.marketing-service-wrap {
 padding: 10%;
 width: 80%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="marketing-services">
  <div class="marketing-service" id="marketing-tab1">
    <div class="marketing-service-wrap total-center">
      <h2 class="marketing-service-title">1</h2>

    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="marketing-service" id="marketing-tab2">
    <div class="marketing-service-wrap total-center">
      <h2 class="marketing-service-title">2</h2>

    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="marketing-service" id="marketing-tab3">
    <div class="marketing-service-wrap total-center">
      <h2 class="marketing-service-title">3</h2>

    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="marketing-service" id="marketing-tab4">
    <div class="marketing-service-wrap total-center">
      <h2 class="marketing-service-title">4</h2>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="marketing1">
  <div class="marketing-section-wrap">
    1
  </div>
</div>
<div id="marketing2">
  <div class="marketing-section-wrap">
    2
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: So I created a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pu0n8z7a/) with the same contents. Chrome was "protecting" me from loading jQuery in SO's snippet for anyone that has the same issue.

Comment: @SunnyPatel Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quite simple just try `$('#marketing'+item_number).children().show()` because `marketing-section-wrap` is `display:none;`

first run this to hide all marketing-section-wrap

```
$('.marketing-section-wrap').hide();
```

then this will show only the one which corresponds to this click.

```
$('#marketing'+item_number).children().show();
```

Comment: Thanks. How can I get the siblings to hide by clicking another option though? I tried giving the `#marketing1` and `#marketing2` a class of `.test` and changed the line to `$('#marketing'+item_number).children().show().siblings('.test').hide();` , but it didn't help.

Comment: I just added classes to my main id's and then applied the `display:none;` to that class, then changed the sibling call to that class as well. Works great. Thanks for the help. Do you know if I am applying the `.active` wrong to the before/after? `.marketing-service:after.active, .marketing-service:before.active`

Comment: i think you want the color to be there when you click on particular div

Comment: I will just ask another question for that. Thank you for your help!

Comment: no you can ask i will be glad to help you. I think you are looking for this https://jsfiddle.net/pu0n8z7a/1/

Comment: Just figured it out. I just read you cannot have a class after a pseudo element. I moved the `.active` to this: `.marketing-service.active:after, .marketing-service.active:before` .. Thank you for your will to help.